# now() cannot be converted to sys_days! I need today's date from now()

Tags: c++, c++20

Having trouble with:

```
auto n = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::sys_days sd = n;
```

Why ? n is a time_point and sd is also time_point (actually time_point<system_clock, days>)??

Comment: You cannot convert from smaller to larger units ify your rep type is integral. That would lose information. You need to either explicitly round the value ot use a floating point rep type, so that a fractional number of days is representable. The other way around (i.e. days to seconds) is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
#include <chrono>

int main() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  auto const n = system_clock::now();
  sys_days sd = floor<days>(n);
}
```

Did I know this off the top of my head? No, of course not. It was in the [examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/operator_days#Example) of cppreference.com.